# error using xlswrite in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm trying to export a `.mat` file to an `.xls` file using xlswrite, but I get the following error:

> Error using xlswrite (line 219)
>   Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:
>   Source: Microsoft Excel
>   Description: Open method of Workbooks class failed
>   Help File: xlmain11.chm
>   Help Context ID: 0

I can successfully export the data to a txt file. The `.mat` file is a 36 x 7 array so we aren't talking about a huge amount of data or anything. I was able to save it as a `.csv`, but I couldn't open the file in excel or the notepad (it basically froze both of the programs). I'm using office 2010 so I tried saving the file as `.xlsx`. I no longer get the error posted above, but I cannot open the file in excel. I get the following error:

> excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

any thoughts?

Comment: This is confusing.  You say you're trying to put a `.mat` file to Excel format, and you say the `.mat` is 36x7.  Important note: `.mat` files can store many variables, and they store metadata like the names of the variables.  Are you trying to save just one variable to an Excel file, and that variable has size 36x7?  Is it class 'double'?  Any special values, like NaN in your matrix?

Comment: It's just one variable and it is a 36 x 7 double. It only contains numbers. No strings or any other special values. I actually think the problem might be with excel. The matrix exports to .txt just fine.

Comment: Please provide the exact command you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete blanks in your filename. Or special characters. ;)